# ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED ao tentar entrar via localhost

Tags: php

Estava codificando e efetuando os testes na minha página php e ao atualizar a página deu este erro: `ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED`. Os demais projetos/páginas estão funcionando e estão abrindo normalmente, só essa que está aparecendo esse erro.

Não sei se é por causa da query que fiz (é **bem** grande)

```
foreach ($nomePessoas as $nomePessoa) {
    foreach (retornaNomeTabelas($nomeTabelas) as $nomeTabela) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeOf($status); $i++) {
            //são 13 horarios
            for ($j = 0; $j < 13; $j++) {
                $where = '`status` NOT IN(0) AND `status` = ' . $status[$i] . ' AND `nomeCompleto` IS NOT NULL ' . ' AND `nomeCompleto`="' . $nomePessoa['nomeCompleto'] . '" ';
                // função buscaPorData retorna string vazia se uma das datas no front não forem preenchidas
                $where .= buscaPorData($GLOBALS['data_inicio'], $GLOBALS['data_fim'], $nomeTabela);
                $where .= stringToTime($j, $j + 1);
                $variaveis = "COUNT(*) AS contadorDeStatus, \"" . $nomePessoa['nomeCompleto'] . "\"  AS  nomeCompleto, " . "\"" . $status[$i] . "\"" . " AS numstatus";
                $turno = "\"" . (8 + $j) . ":00:00 - " . (8 + $j + 1) . ":00:00\" AS horario , ";
                $nomeTab = "\"" . $nomeTabela['front-tb-nome'] . "\"" . " AS nome_tabela ";
                $sql[] = "( " . " SELECT " . $turno . $variaveis . " , " . $nomeTab . " FROM " . $nomeTabela['db-tab-nome'] . " WHERE " . $where . " ) ";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Coloca o código, qual banco é?

Comment: efetuei as alterações

Comment: Algum dos codigos estao fazendo loop na conexao?

Comment: eu monto a query e guardo em uma string,  depois mando executar... além disso,  faço uso de union all também (dependendo da escolha da pessoa, a query fica gigantesca)